# linux + sysctl -a + from where sysctl -a print all kernel parameters

Tags: linux, redhat, kernel, sysctl

we have linux machine redhat 6

when we print all paramers from /etc/sysctl.conf we see only ~20
but when we perform sysctl -a we see more then 200

so from where sysctl -a print all these parameters ?

or for example

when we do

```
    sysctl -w variable=value
```

how to know where variable should be saved ?

second

how to know each parameters if this dynamic or static ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `-a` of `sysctl` prints all available options as stated in the manual.

```
-a, --all
     Display all values currently available.
```

These options come from the built-in or loaded Linux kernel modules. Some if not all modules provide some variables that can be tuned via `sysctl`. The `/etc/sysctl.conf` includes the variables that have been changed. Any variable uses its default value when not changed.

Please, note that there are multiple files to load system parameters like files under `/etc/sysctl.d/`.

If you want to know whether a variable can be changed or not, you can look at the corresponding file under `/proc/sys`. Some files (variables) are read-only while others can be read and written.

Here is an example of one changeable variable (1st one) and one read-only (second) from `/proc/sys/kernel/`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr  4 10:23 shmmax
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr  4 10:14 version
```

Comment: regarding - built-in or loaded Linux kernel modules , how to know the path of this modules , second how to know if variable is statis or dinamic ( dinamic is value that change )

Comment: in my redhat machine we not have  /etc/sysctl.d/ folder

Comment: do you know how to verify if kernel parameter is dynamic ? ( I mean the OS change this value )

Comment: The kernel documentation on https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ typically explains the kernel runtime parameters, their default and accepted values. A google search `site:www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ <parameter-name>` is often the quickest to find the appropriate manual page. And anything not overruled from the locations explained in `man sysctl` or manually by an administrator with `echo value > /proc/sys/section/module/parameter` or similar should be at the default setting

Comment: yes but I am asking about howto know  kernel parameter is dynamic ( that change according to the OS state ? )